# Button Inner Shadow in black and white

Tags: button, shadow

i want to create a Inner-Shadow like on this website:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

But i want to have the shadows on the right and bottom side colored white.
I really have no more ideas.

Always when i click my button i only get the white shadow. So the white shadow overwrites the black?

Thats how far i am:

```js
$('#button').mouseup(function () {
    $('#button').removeClass('shadowBlack shadowWhite')
});

$('#button').mousedown(function() {
    $('#button').addClass('shadowBlack shadowWhite')
});
```

```css
.shadowBlack {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 200px 200px 0px -186px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 200px 200px 0px -186px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: inset 200px 200px 0px -186px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.shadowWhite {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 0px -186px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 0px -186px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 0px -186px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

Comment: HTML is missed in your jfiddle and so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Found it out:

.shadow{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 9px 9px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75).inset -10px -10px 15px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 9px 9px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), inset -10px -10px 15px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
box-shadow: inset 9px 9px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75), inset -10px -10px 15px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

```js
$('#button').mouseup(function () {
    $('#button').removeClass('shadowBlack shadowWhite')
});

$('#button').mousedown(function() {
    $('#button').addClass('shadowBlack shadowWhite')
});
```

```css
.shadowBlack {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 200px 200px 0px -186px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 200px 200px 0px -186px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: inset 200px 200px 0px -186px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.shadowWhite {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 0px -186px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 0px -186px rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: inset -200px -200px 0px -186px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```